# I want a JComboBox to update the suggestions with what the user typed

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

I have an **editable** JComboBox.

How can I make it do something like: The user types "**y**" and then it only gives suggestions from the database that **start** with the letter "**y**", then he types "**ya**" and then only suggestions(from the database) appear that start with "**ya**" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/) may help you with what you are trying to achieve
**OR**
you can try to use `AutoCompleteDecorator` [here's the documentation](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html).

**Edit**: Although I haven't tested nor did I went deeply in this resource, it may be worth to look at [Programcreek.com](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator) as they demonstrate 7 Java examples for `AutoCompleteDecorator`